How to make effect of custom elementor control to loop-carousel widget from pro-elements plugin?
I have wordpress site with pro-elements plugin and loop-carousel widget is one of the best widget to set particular category's products and show in slider. My requirements are like i want to set one brand selector in the elementor settings. Whenever i select and save any brand from that, loop-carousel widget products should belongs to that brand.
I have set custom select control for loop-carousel widget in elementor settings using this hook.
add_action("elementor/element/loop-carousel/section_query/after_section_end", "custom_brand_control");

I have tried to use loop-carousel widget hooks from pro-elements plugin files, tried to use some elementor hooks (given below) also, but unable to get any solutions.
"elementor/element/loop-carousel/section_query/after_section_end" (with $element and $args parameters)
"woocommerce_shortcode_products_query"

